# How to add or replace page in android layout view

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to use andoid's [`BottomNavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) to make iOS-like tabbed page in Xamarin Forms cross platform app, by making a platform specific renderer in the android project. Basically I add a layout with a bottomnavigationview in it, and in the renderer add this view to the root activity, and create menu items based on the forms tabbed page. Now the problem how can I add/show the current page of the forms tabbed page to the android layout, and replace it when bar item is clicked. I found even I called `RemoveAllViews` in the renderer, the content page in the tabbed page will occupy the entire screen, and it will even cover the bottom bar. So if any one content page of the tabbed page is visible, it will occupy the entire screen. Also android's `AddView` method only accepts android view, it does not accept forms view.

The BottomNav layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
android:orientation="vertical">
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
  android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
  android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
  app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
  app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
  app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Renderer OnElementChanged:

```
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        TabbedPage oe = e.OldElement;
        TabbedPage ne = e.NewElement;
        int id = 1000;
        foreach(Page p in ne.Children)
        {
            items.Add(new Item
            {
                text = p.Title,
                icon = p.Icon,
                page = p,
                id = id++,
            });
            p.IsVisible = false; // without this, page show full screen and covers the bottom bar
        }

        RemoveAllViews();
        Activity activity = this.Context as Activity;
        view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BottomNav, this, false);
        AddView(view);
        layout = view.FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.rootLayout);
        // add current page to layout, or replace layout with page? and How?
        //
        //

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
            FindViewById(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.NavigationItemSelected += BottomNavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;

        Android.Support.V7.View.Menu.MenuBuilder menu = bottomNavigationView.Menu as Android.Support.V7.View.Menu.MenuBuilder;
        menu.Clear();

        foreach(Item i in items)
        {
            IMenuItem mi = menu.Add(0, i.id, 0, i.text);
            mi.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);
        }
```

EDIT: add more code and screenshots

My expected layout is like this, without showing the pages from the XF tabbedpage, the main part of red is the `FrameLayout` of id `rootLayout`, the goal is to add the current page of the tabbedpage to the Framelayout and show it, while when items in the BottomNavigationView is clicked, switch the FrameLayout to show other pages. But this screen is only possible by making all the pages invisible by:

```
        foreach (Page p in e.NewElement.Children)
        {
            p.IsVisible = false;
        }
```

[image: android view]

If without the setting visible to false, the subpage will occupy entire screen:
[image]

My test XF tabbed page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BottomTabbed"
        x:Class="BottomTabbed.TabbedPage1"
        NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
      <ContentPage Title="Tab 1" BackgroundColor="Green" />
      <ContentPage Title="Tab 2" BackgroundColor="Blue"/>
      <ContentPage Title="Tab 3" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
      <ContentPage Title="Tab 4" BackgroundColor="Gray" />
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Either use the following component, or look at the code to see how it is implemented https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF

Comment: I checked it out, it is not using the android bottomnavigationview, it is using a relativelayout and buttons in it.

Comment: Which renderer are you trying to customize? Since I didn't see all code of your custom renderer, but seems you're trying `TabbedPageRenderer`?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to customize TabbedPageRenderer, but not directly inherit from TabbedPageRenderer because I need to overrite the layout and use android's view, so I'm inherit from VisualElementRenderer<TabbedPage>.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, your last comment didn't notify me. I wrote an answer below, I really think you don't need to customize a `TabbedPage`.

Comment: I used TabbedPage because I am indeed making a tabbed page with 4 sub pages, and this is xamarin forms app, so I'm also need the tabbed page in ios project too. I'm customizing it because I'd like to unify the UI appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you don't need `TabbedPage` at all, all you need is a view with `BottomNavigationView` and `FrameLayout` for fragments. Then you can customize a `ViewRenderer` for this.

First, create a subclass of `View` in PCL for example:

```
public class BottomTabbedView:View
{
}
```

Then implement its renderer in android client project:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(BottomTabbedView),typeof(BottomTabbedViewRenderer))]
namespace PackageNameSpace.Droid
{
    public class BottomTabbedViewRenderer:ViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                // Instantiate the native control and assign it to the Control property with
                // the SetNativeControl method
                var context = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
                var bottomnav_view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.bottomnav_view, this, false);
                var frame = bottomnav_view.FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.rootLayout);
                var navi = bottomnav_view.FindViewById<BottomNavigationView>(Resource.Id.bottom_navigation);
                SetNativeControl(bottomnav_view);
            }

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                // Configure the control and subscribe to event handlers
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't finish all code here for the logic of `BottomNavigationView` and `FrameLayout`, you should be able implement the logic inside this `ViewRenderer`. The code should be similar as the one for Xamarin.Android.

Then you can use this view as a normal view control inside `ContentPage` of XF for example like this：

```
<local:BottomTabbedView/>
```

Comment: The problem is how to add subpages of type ContentPage into framelayout so that it can show as part of the big view. Because Page is not an android View, so AddView will not work

Comment: @fluter, yeah, my suggestion was directly complete the logic so with the view for other pages in the android client project. But if you want to know how to expose the native android method `AddView` to PCL, I will update my answer later.

Comment: I mean if I go with this approach I will have to make a custom renderer for iOS and UWP projects too, but I only need to customize android, because the native controls of the other two platforms works just fine.

Comment: @fluter, no, you can embed different view for each platform, if it goes well on iOS and UWP, then we don't need to make a custom rendrer for them,  you may check this [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790186.aspx). But I'm confused with your layout right now, could you please maybe show an image to explain it? Maybe we can find better way for it in Android platform.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question with image and code.

Comment: So I think I need to be able to add the current content page to the FrameLayout. From the [builtin renderer](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/TabbedPageRenderer.cs), I think I also need to use a ViewPager or similar because it is multiple pages and only one is shown.

Comment: @fluter, OK, great. And maybe this [BottomTabbedPage](https://github.com/naxam/bottomtabbedpage-xamarin-forms) can makes your work easier.